# How to access fields of a Generic type in Kotlin?

Tags: android, kotlin, generics, kotlin-reified-type-parameters

I have a Generic class.

```
class GenericsClassExample<T>(
        var data: T
)
```

I have another class which I'm passing in place of T.

```
data class MyDataClass1(val id: String, val value: String)
```

And I'm instantiating Generic Class like :

```
val genericClass = GenericClass<MyDataClass1>()
```

I would like to know how to access the fields (`id` and `value`) from `genericClass` object without knowing the type of the class I'm passing, i.e. I could also pass another class like `MyDataClass1` say `MyDataClass2` which also has its own fields.

Comment: If you don't know type of class, how would you know which field you want to access?

Comment: @mightyWOZ , what if all the classes I'm gonna pass have a common field which I'd like to access. Is there anyway to achieve it?

Comment: Only if the common field is defined in an interface they all implement or a class they are all subclasses of. Then make that interface or superclass the generic type.

Comment: @Tenfour04 but then you wouldn't need generics (compile-time polymorphism) and would just be using boring old run-time polymorphism. Rakesh, the JVM does not support this. JVM generics are evaluated where the generic is *defined*, unlike C++ which evaluates templates when the template is *instantiated*.

Comment: Unless there’s some other reason they’re using the generics. But anyway this question is ancient and OP is probably an expert on generics by now. ;) @user1332148